# Where is the difference between using `pdfimages` from poppler-utils and using the one provided by xpdf-utils for image extraction?

Tags: graphics, pdf, default-programs, extract

I need to extract a bunch of images from a PDF file. `pdfimages` should do the job. When trying to install, I got two alternatives `poppler-utils` and `xpdf-utils` so i wonder, whicht to choose.

Where are the differences, what are pros/cons of each alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are forks: used to be the same but someone decided to go another direction. Poppler-utils is the favored one. Debian already removed xpdf-utils from the code base. From [Ubuntu bug #697119](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xpdf/+bug/697119) and [debian bug #622343](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=622343) they also are in conflict with each other due to sharing the same file names.

xpdf-utils seems to be better at some things but from the 2nd link: "These minor regression bugs should be submitted against poppler (preferably upstream poppler) where they can actually get fixed."

Poppler is used in Gimp and Evince so that seems to be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

The `poppler` library was originally based on `xpdf`, but improved to better work as a library and to use more modern rendering techniques.

So the difference would be that one version is based on the original `xpdf` code base, while the other comes from the `poppler` fork.

Since you are probably already using the `poppler` library as a PDF viewer, you may as well use the version from `poppler-utils`.

Comment: actually, I don't use any of them as no graphical pdf reader is installed